# SQL INSERT and RETURNING clause logic

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert some user registration data into my data table.

`u_id | name | username | password | email`

`$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO mfbusers (name, username, password, email) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$email') RETURNING u_id");`

I'm really not sure how to then use the returned u_id to insert into the u_id column. I have tried the Data Modifying CTE method but that logic only makes sense to me when I have multiple tables with a relational database.

Any suggestions on how to insert the `u_id` value into the `u_id` column?

All the other variables are written properly into my database. It's just the `u_id` column is blank upon registration.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? The column in row is already assigned, probably from some sequence.

Comment: Isn't `u_id` the typical `INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 3):

Change your u_id column to SERIAL and the values will be assigned automatically